# Baki manga reading order?

Tags: grappler-baki

I'm interested in reading Baki but there to there are a lot of Baki series. Which are

1. Baki
2. Baki Gaiden Kenjin
3. Baki Gaiden Kizuzura
4. Baki Gaiden Scarface
5. Baki the Grappler Gaiden
6. Baki Tokubetsuhen Saga
7. Baki Dou
8. Grappler Baki
9. Grappler Baki Fighting
10. Hanma Baki

So are the order of reading them?

Comment: order of release? Chronological order? order of in-universe events?

Comment: As I was typing this question since I'm about to start reading the series as well this question popped up and answered me perfectly. Fantastic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading Order:

1. [Grappler Baki](https://myanimelist.net/manga/11425/Grappler_Baki) - 1991 to 1999
2. [Grappler Baki Gaiden](https://myanimelist.net/manga/73425/Grappler_Baki_Gaiden) - 1999, *Grappler Baki Spin-off*
3. [Baki: New Grappler Baki](https://myanimelist.net/manga/5157/Baki__New_Grappler_Baki) - 1999 to 2005, *Grappler Baki Sequel*
4. [Baki Tokubetsu-hen Saga](https://myanimelist.net/manga/72785/Baki_Tokubetsu-hen_Saga) - 2002, *Baki: New Grappler Baki Side Story*
5. [Baki Gaiden: Kizuzura](https://myanimelist.net/manga/72789/Baki_Gaiden__Kizuzura) - 2012 to 2013, *Baki: New Grappler Baki Side Story*
6. [Baki Gaiden: Kenjin](https://myanimelist.net/manga/72787/Baki_Gaiden__Kenjin) - 2013 to ?, *Baki: New Grappler Baki Side Story*
7. [Hanma Baki](https://myanimelist.net/manga/7760/Hanma_Baki) - 2005 to 2012, *Baki: New Grappler Baki Sequel*
8. [Baki Gaiden: Scarface](https://myanimelist.net/manga/13122/Baki_Gaiden__Scarface) - 2005 to ?, *Baki: New Grappler Baki & Hanma Baki Side Story*
9. [Baki-dou](https://myanimelist.net/manga/72299/Baki-dou) - 2014 to 2018, *Hanma Baki Sequel*